# How to make a class object available during the entire life of the request in Asp .Net Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Here is my code. I have written login to validate the token, for valid token return user object. but unable to find way to make it available across controllers.

I don't want to use Identity.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string AUTH_TOKEN = "AuthToken";

    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        AllowAnonymousAttribute allowAnonymousAttribute = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (allowAnonymousAttribute != null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Contains(AUTH_TOKEN))
        {
            var authToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues(AUTH_TOKEN).First();
            var user = Utility.GetUserByToken(authToken);

            if (user != null)
            {
                //
                // how to make this `user` object available across the controllers
                //

                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new CustomError() { Code = 100, Message = "Invalid Access Token" });
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new CustomError() { Code = 100, Message = "Invalid Access Token" });
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help...

Comment: It is very rare when more then on Controller involved in handling of single request in WebAPI case (it somewhat more common in ASP.Net MVC for child actions, but I never seen need for it in WebAPI). Are you sure you are asking for sharing information during single HTTP request  and not "browser session"?

Comment: Actually I want know the userId from the `user` object so that I can use it for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is a bit unclear - I assume you are referring to this line:

```
var user = Utility.GetUserByToken(authToken);
```

If so, then I might have a solution. So the fundamental problem is that you cannot simply save this variable where you currently are in the current controller, you need to understand the context you are working in - Every time a different user makes a request a different user models get created in the current controller. To have access to the user model across my app whenever a user makes a request, I do the following:

First you need to hook into the request receiving process of ASP.NET. This can be done inside the `Global.asax.cs` file, but I prefer to keep it clean and create a `PartialGlobal` class and mark the `Global.asax.cs` as partial.

From

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
```

To

```
public partial class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
```

Then create the `PartialGlobal` Class:

```
 public partial class MvcApplication
{
    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];

        //For API users
        if (authHeader != null)
        {
            var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);
            if (authHeaderVal.Scheme.Equals("Basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeaderVal.Parameter))
                {
                    AuthenticateUser(authHeaderVal.Parameter);
                }
            }
        }
        //For Regular Website Users
        else
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                //Extract the forms authentication cookie
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                // If caching userData field then extract
                var userModel = UsersBLL.DeserializeObject(authTicket.UserData);
                var principal = new UserPrincipal(userModel);
                SetPrincipal(principal);
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool AuthenticateUser(string credentials)
    {
        var model = UsersBLL.DecryptToken(credentials);
        if (!model.RefUser.HasValue)
        {
            return false;
        }

        SetPrincipal(new UserPrincipal(model));

        return true;
    }

    private static void SetPrincipal(UserPrincipal principal)
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
    }
}
```

The `UserPrincipal` Class:

```
public class UserPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
    //Just a class with details like name,age etc.
    public UserModel Model { get; set; }

    public UserPrincipal(UserModel model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
        this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(model.Email);
    }        
}
```

Note the line in the `PartialGLobal` class: `var model = UsersBLL.DecryptToken(credentials);`. Here I simply use a method I created to de-crypt my token string so it can be deserialized, you probably won't have/need this.

The essential part is this last step of the `PartialGlobal` class:

```
private static void SetPrincipal(UserPrincipal principal)
{
     Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
     if (HttpContext.Current != null)
     {
         HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
     }
}
```

If you have the context know about your user, you can access it anywhere by simply calling:

```
var principal = (UserPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in this case need implement IPrincipal for UserPrincipal. Could you please share code of UserPrincipal?

Comment: Sure :). Updated my post.

Comment: Sure, No Problem!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to Extend the ApiController which is what your controllers are using as the base class.

Define a CustomController

```
public class CustomController : ApiController
{
    projected User _user;

}
```

For all the other controller use this as a base class and the _user object should be accessible from all the controllers.

Comment: how would initialize the _user object?